# Get value of Select Dropdownlist from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a DropdownList which I have created using the Select Box as you can see below, now I am not sure how to get the value from code behind Is there anything I can use such as findcontrol in order to get the value. FYI: I am doing this in MVC using the aspx view engine not razor

Dropdownlist code:

```
<Select id="subjects">
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="English">English</option>
    <option value="Science">Science</option>
    <option value="History">History</option>
    <option value="Geography">Geography</option>
</Select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should move data between View and Controller using Models. The model is sent to the view when the page is loaded, the model is post back again when you submit the form.

Comment: Is it not possible to use findcontrol?

Comment: When you start a new MVC project in Visual Studio (at least from MVC 3 and above, maybe even for versions 1 and 2) you get a working website which shows this. I think it would also be helpful to take a look here: http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/developing-asp-net-mvc-4-web-applications-jump-start